Scrapy spider running even if its closed
So the spider is running even after it is closed, it keeps on dumping stats 0 items/min
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://www.raceentry.com/races/the-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon/2024/register 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://www.raceentry.com/races/the-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon/2024/register 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/participate-for-free-when-you-refer-friends-2/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/participate-for-free-when-you-refer-friends-2/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/the-kauai-marathon-merchandise-is-available-on-support-aloha/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/the-kauai-marathon-merchandise-is-available-on-support-aloha/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/finish-line-video-contest-vote-now/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/finish-line-video-contest-vote-now/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/race-founders-jeff-and-liz-sacchinis-final-thoughts-2/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/race-founders-jeff-and-liz-sacchinis-final-thoughts-2/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/final-press-release-for-the-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/final-press-release-for-the-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/finish-line-video-contest-sponsored-by-alaska-airlines-announced/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/finish-line-video-contest-sponsored-by-alaska-airlines-announced/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/south-and-east-side-of-kauai-suggested-courses/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/south-and-east-side-of-kauai-suggested-courses/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/the-2020-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon-race-instructions/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/the-2020-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon-race-instructions/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/2020-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon-swag-details/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/2020-virtual-kauai-marathon-and-half-marathon-swag-details/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/virtual-keiki-run-announced-by-wilcox-health-and-the-kauai-marathon/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/virtual-keiki-run-announced-by-wilcox-health-and-the-kauai-marathon/ 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com/blog/page/6/?et_blog 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://www.instagram.com/thekauaimarathon 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 5): https://thekauaimarathon.com 
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 45766,
 'downloader/request_count': 117,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 117,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5253925,
 'downloader/response_count': 117,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 114,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 2,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 687,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 164.249327,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 3, 20, 4, 11, 919593),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 242,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'item_scraped_count': 98,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 11533,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 55,
 'memusage/max': 368799744,
 'memusage/startup': 173932544,
 'offsite/domains': 40,
 'offsite/filtered': 302,
 'playwright/context_count': 2,
 'playwright/context_count/max_concurrent': 1,
 'playwright/context_count/persistent/False': 2,
 'playwright/context_count/remote/False': 2,
 'playwright/page_count': 114,
 'playwright/page_count/max_concurrent': 4,
 'playwright/request_count': 4227,
 'playwright/request_count/method/GET': 4137,
 'playwright/request_count/method/POST': 90,
 'playwright/request_count/navigation': 157,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/document': 157,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/fetch': 4,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/font': 205,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/image': 584,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/other': 58,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/ping': 11,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/script': 1743,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/stylesheet': 1386,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/xhr': 79,
 'playwright/response_count': 4203,
 'playwright/response_count/method/GET': 4113,
 'playwright/response_count/method/POST': 90,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/document': 147,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/fetch': 1,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/font': 205,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/image': 576,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/other': 57,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/ping': 11,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/script': 1742,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/stylesheet': 1385,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/xhr': 79,
 'request_depth_max': 5,
 'response_received_count': 116,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 114,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 114,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 114,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 114,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 3, 20, 1, 27, 670266)}
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: Browser context closed: 'default' (persistent=False, remote=False)
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing browser
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
2024-06-03 20:04:11 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: Browser context closed: 'default' (persistent=False, remote=False)
2024-06-03 20:04:12 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing browser
2024-06-03 20:04:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:05:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:06:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_timeout)
2024-06-03 20:06:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:07:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:08:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:09:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:10:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:11:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-06-03 20:12:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 96 items (at 0 items/min)

class GrantsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "npos"
    reported_links = []
    link_extractor = LinkExtractor(unique=True)
    npos = {}
    async def errback_close_page(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        if page:
            await page.close()
            print(f"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx {page} closed on error xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    def start_requests(self):
        if not self.start_urls and hasattr(self, "start_url"):
            raise AttributeError(
                "Crawling could not start: 'start_urls' not found "
                "or empty (but found 'start_url' attribute instead, "
                "did you miss an 's'?)"
            )
        for url in self.start_urls:
            npo = self.npos[url]
            logging.info("### crawl: %s", url)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, callback=self.my_parse, dont_filter=True,meta={"playwright": True, "playwright_include_page": True,'dont_redirect': True}, cb_kwargs={"npo": npo},
                errback=self.errback_close_page
            )


I was previously facing same kind of problem but that time debug log showed me that it was due to meta-refresh-redirect and i was able to solve that using this solution - Scrapy - How to stop meta refresh redirect?
but this time debugging console gives me nothing to work with , any idea what should I do ?

do you mean page.close() is closing spider? As for me it closes playwright but not spider.

2024-06-03 20:06:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider(closespider_timeout)
The CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT is closing the spider , but still the stats are getting dumped ,making the code get stuck

see image on Architecture overview — Scrapy 2.11.2 documentation. It shows how works Scrapy. Spider is only one part, and data can be in other part when you close spider, and engine may still execute them. In code I see word playwright - maybe it is still working.

so what worked for me is adding dont_filter=true in request and adding DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True in settings.py

also to further ensure that the error doesn't occur at some point again, I decreased CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
